# have trouble understanding explain analyze query plan in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been playing around with **explain analyze** to understand performance of the functions I have written previously basically deleting records from a particular time period in DB.

The peculiar thing I noticed was that the execution time period keeps on changing drastically for the same function.It shows highest value when i call the function for the 1'st time and when I try to call second time or later the execution time keeps changing however lower than the first time.
The amount of records have been updated and kept constant after every delete function call.Please find the report as below :

```
  pcwh=# explain analyze select DelWeeklyWiseRecords ('raj_weekly_records');
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.782..2.782 rows=1 loops=1)
Total runtime: 2.815 ms
(2 rows)

pcwh=# explain analyze select DelWeeklyWiseRecords ('raj_testWeek_records');
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.566..0.567 rows=1 loops=1)
Total runtime: 0.597 ms
(2 rows)

pcwh=# explain analyze select DelWeeklyWiseRecords ('raj_weekly_records');  
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.246..0.246 rows=1 loops=1)
Total runtime: 0.257 ms
(2 rows)
```

I have run the analyze query on the same table repeatedly each time the number of records where kept same.But I see varying results. So how do I check the performance ?

Comment: "It shows highest value when i call the function for the first time... " That is normal: First time, results are fetched from hard disk, then when you repeat 2nd time, results are cached in RAM.

Comment: but then even later there is a drastic difference sometimes it shows lesser value if it was a minute difference it was understandable...but the results keep varying.

Comment: Check this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59563/postgres-explain-analyze-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to be looking at the underlying query within the functions to check the performance here? The function call can be quicker for numerous reasons.

- less rows to delete on subsequent runs
- data is in cache rather than disk
- query plan already known so less parse time
- etc etc

Plus a shorter time has got to be a good thing providing your function is performing the task that is asked of it?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier the data or number of rows were kept same after delete function was performed and repeated

Answer (score 0):

The actual time will depend on what other queries are running and other processes that might be accessing the disk, using cpu, etc and that fact that after the first time the results are likely to be cached. It is the cost that is actually relevant in the output of explain, as this gives a unitless notion of the cost of fetching the data from disk plus running the query based on statistics, indexes, etc. In your case this is (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) in every case, so there is nothing to worry about.

Note this line from the official docs: "The most critical part of the display is the estimated statement execution cost, which is the planner's guess at how long it will take to run the statement (measured in cost units that are arbitrary, but conventionally mean disk page fetches)" at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html